# Linked list looping and addfirst

Tags: java, list, linked-list

Why this is not working? I am looping on a trxFifoArray List and passing its object items to result List. I need to split some amounts in 2 so I need to addFirst this 2 amount to result list. The amounts are in an arrayList [-9.0000, -6.0000]. So I loop the amount list to do the addFirst on result and the items are added but with same amount even the list has 2 different amount.

```
    LinkedList<InvtQaTracer> trxFifoArray = new LinkedList<InvtQaTracer>();
    LinkedList<InvtQaTracer> result = new LinkedList<InvtQaTracer>();
    InvtQaTracer trx = new InvtQaTracer();

    int trxDocoRef = 0;
    for (int j = list.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        trx = list.get(j);
        System.out.printf("%12.4f %4s%10d  %12s%n", trx.getTrxQty(), trx.getDocType(), trx.getOrdNo(), trx.getLocNo());
        List<BigDecimal> auxAmounts = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

        if (trx.getDocType().compareTo("OV") == 0
                || trx.getDocType().compareTo("XV") == 0) {
                    //Do something ...

        } else {
            BigDecimal auxAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            Boolean needRemove = false;
            for (InvtQaTracer tFifo : trxFifoArray) {
                if (trx.getDocType().compareTo("IT") == 0) {

                            auxAmounts.add(tFifo.getTrxQty().negate());

                } 
            }
            if (needRemove) {
                Iterator<InvtQaTracer> iterator = trxFifoArray.iterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    InvtQaTracer iqt = iterator.next();
                    if (iqt.getTrxQty().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                        count++;
                        iterator.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!auxAmounts.isEmpty()) {
            for (BigDecimal asss : auxAmounts) {
                System.out.println(asss);
                trx.setTrxQty(asss);
                result.addFirst(trx);
            }
        } else {
            result.addFirst(trx);
        }
        for (InvtQaTracer invtQT : trxFifoArray) {
            System.out.printf("%20s%2s%12.4f %10d  %12s%10d%n", "                                               ----------------> ", invtQT.getDocType(), invtQT.getTrxQty(), invtQT.getOrdNo(), invtQT.getLocNo(), invtQT.getDocNo());
        }
    }
```

This code add two records with -6.000000 value even it is printing out both of them. I hope you understand the code. Please Help!!!

Thanks.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This code can't even compile since you are declaring the variables `result` and `auxAmounts` two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am finding a problem in the code.
Code needs to be updated like this

```
if (!auxAmounts.isEmpty()) {
            LinkedList<InvtQaTracer> result = new LinkedList<InvtQaTracer>();
            //Updated Here
            InvtQaTracer trx = null;
            List<BigDecimal> auxAmounts = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>(); //[-9.000000, -6.000000]
            for (BigDecimal asss : auxAmounts) {
                System.out.println(asss);
            //Updated Here
            trx = new InvtQaTracer();
                trx.setTrxQty(asss);
                result.addFirst(trx);
            }
        } else {
            result.addFirst(trx);
        }
```

One more change identified is 
inside the else loop  needRemove value is set to false by default and below checking whether it is true in if loop. think this one can be removed.

Comment: That works, Thank you! The result, trx and auxAmounts are declared before so I just removed from here. I added only the line trx = new InvtQaTracer(); and it works OK. Now I just need set the rest of the fields of the object